# jquery trigger hover on anchor

Tags: jquery, triggers, hover, mouseover

I'm using jQuery to develop in web environment.

I want to know why

```
 $("#a#trigger").trigger('mouseenter');
 $("#a#trigger").trigger('hover');
 $("#a#trigger").trigger('mouseover');
```

All 3 of those aren't working to activate a hover function that I have.

```
$(function() {


        $('a#trigger').hover(function(e) {
          $('div#pop-up').show();

             }, function() {
          $('div#pop-up').hide();
        });

     });

      });
```

`a#trigger` is the name of the anchor, and `#pop-up` is a div element in my web.

The problem is that I want to mouse over some event in FullCalendar plugin and those functions aren't working.
Thanks.

Comment: don't use tagname in front of ID in selector, is less efficient than using ID alone

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You are on the right track, the problem is the extra `#` in  the selector, just remove the first hash:

```
$("a#trigger").trigger('mouseenter');
```

Note that since IDs must be unique, there is no need to specify the element type, `$('#trigger')` is more efficient.

Also note that:

> **Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9:** The name `"hover"` used as a shorthand for the string `"mouseenter mouseleave"`. It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine `event.type` to determine whether the event is `mouseenter` or `mouseleave`. Do not confuse the `"hover"` pseudo-event-name with the `.hover()` method, which accepts one or two functions.

Comment: wow im blind like hell after 25 hours of programming, thank you very much.
and its was Mouseenter by the way..hover not working
@undefined

Comment: I don't know why I failed using `trigger(mouseenter)` somehow, but end up success by writing a `.hover` class and do `addClass('hover')`.

Answer (score 10):

Your jQuery selector should be written as e.g.

```
$('a#trigger');
```

instead of `$('#a#trigger');`

In jQuery a # in a selector matches an id. In this case `trigger` is an id, but `a` is an HTML element and requires no prefix.

Your final code would be:

```
$("a#trigger").trigger('mouseenter');
$("a#trigger").trigger('hover');
$("a#trigger").trigger('mouseover');
```