# Having hover effects on HTML element without actually hovering via jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I've been trying is to hover an HTML element via jQuery/JavaScript.

[image]

Here we have an `<a>`, which reads "Beer".

This will have an underline when the mouse pointer is hovering it in the following way.

[image]

The line is created of the `:before` selector.

I'm wondering if it's possible to hover any of those `<a>` with JS, so that one of those `<a>` is hovered without the user actually hovering it.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Just in case, here is CSS which created the underline. I made this by referring to [this tutorial](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/css-trick-animating-link-underlines/).

```
.nav-link{
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-link:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.nav-link:hover:before {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Comment: you are trying to trigger a hover event, right? ... might want to check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074815/jquery-trigger-hover-on-anchor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make them seperate classes and use `.addClass()`

```
.nav-link-hover {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

and in your jQuery

```
$('.nav-link').addClass('nav-link-hover');
```

Comment: And if you want to remove the class after you are done, use `.removeClass('nav-link-hover')`